# Disable Text Replacement in Mac Application

Tags: objective-c, macos, text, replace

What's the procedure to disable Text Replacement inside a Mac OSX application written in Objective-C?

The application I'm currently debugging is using lots of NSTextFields and
from what I've found out NSTextFields doesn't seem to have the same methods as NSTextViews for disabling this:

- setAutomaticQuoteSubstitutionEnabled:NO
- setAutomaticTextReplacementEnabled:NO

This is although what I'm trying to achieve for all text fields within the application so what's the procedure in order to get this working?
Note that the user shouldn't be able to enable this at any point and it should also override the global settings in System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Text.

Comment: Basically what I'm trying to achieve is to toggle the same method as the Edit-Substitutions-Text Replacement on application startup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a text field has the keyboard focus (when it is the first responder of the window), a text **view** is added to the window on top of the text field and handles editing for it. This text view is called the [field editor](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/TextFonts/Conceptual/CocoaTextArchitecture/TextFieldsAndViews/TextFieldsAndViews.html).

There are various places where you can customize the field editor. Since you have many text fields, you may want to use the window delegate method `-windowWillReturnFieldEditor:toObject:`. It can just create an `NSTextView`, set its `fieldEditor` property to true, set `automaticTextReplacementEnabled` to false, and return that. It should probably only create this object once, the first time it's requested, and then return it for all calls, for efficiency.

Other approaches include using a custom `NSWindow` subclass which overrides `-fieldEditor:forObject:` or using a custom `NSTextFieldCell` class for your text fields, which overrides `-setUpFieldEditorAttributes:`